# Blender python : How to set object appearance in viewport?

Tags: python

I want to set object to be as textured or wire like in

> Property/object/viewport Display/Display as ..

How to do this using python ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mouse over see the property test in console**

[image]
*Make sure python tooltips and developer extras is checked*

Mousing over the desired field..

```
python: Object.display_type
```

Testing in the console

```
>>> C.object.display_type
'WIRE'
```

Get it deliberately wrong to see what options are available.

```
>>> C.object.display_type = 'XXX'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "XXX" not found
         in ('BOUNDS', 'WIRE', 'SOLID', 'TEXTURED')

>>> C.object.display_type = 'SOLID'
```