# Is there any way to change viewport preview pass through script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have mastering blender, but i'm absolutely beginner in python or blender script.
i just can use the script trough copy from the "Info" area then paste to "Text Editor"
then Run it.

but i get confused to change preview passes trough script

the line from the "Info" (when i switch the passes) is

```
bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].(null) = 'NORMAL'
```

i copy and paste to the editor, so like this

```
import bpy
bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].(null) = 'NORMAL'
```

and the script won't run, its get invalid syntax

any help will be appreciated
thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Developer Extras**

Relying on the info area to write scripts is IMO not the way to go.

Some posts explaining how to find what the property is.

[Changing the shading type in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137844/changing-the-shading-type-in-python)

[Blender python : How to set object appearance in viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127486/blender-python-how-to-set-object-appearance-in-viewport/127488#127488)

With developer extras turned on mousing over the property

[image]

Telling us the type and its property of interest [`View3DShading.render_pass`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DShading.html#bpy.types.View3DShading.render_pass)  For a 3D viewport, will find any property setting belongs to the space.   Scrolling to References at bottom of page confirms this *ie* `SpaceView3D.shading` is an instance of `View3DShading`

To the python console:

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'VIEW_3D')
(3, 'TEXT_EDITOR')
```

Area 2 is a view 3d, its active space

```
>>> space = C.screen.areas[2].spaces.active
```

The render pass property of shading group

```
>>> space.shading.render_pass
'COMBINED'
```

Set to something else.

```
>>> space.shading.render_pass = 'MIST'
>>>
```

Note in a script to run from the context of a view3d, then use

```
space = context.space_data
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, and i've try it.
but sadly its only work in "Material Preview" not in cycles render preview as well

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187390/why-this-simple-script-only-work-in-material-preview-not-in-cycles-render-pre